# Saving ECX registers before procedure calls and manipulatation of ecx register

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers, irvine32

I have some trouble trying to save the ecx register on the stack and then using the ecx register for the loop inside a procedure call. The output that I get from the numbers is bound by the ecx that is in the main and not the procedure. The nature of the problem is taking strings in Masm then changing it to a number using the ascii chart table and then putting these new numbers into a array. But when I enter the number from the user it is bound by the loop of the main, for example if I have an ecx of 3 then it will only take the three first numbers of what I enter. First code is the main, then the procedure followed by two macros. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried pushing the ecx register inside of the procedure and then popping it after the procedure is over but that just messes up my loop in the main. I have also tried saving all the registers right at the beginning of the procedure call using the pushad and then popping them all back at the end of the code using the popad. That also didn't work.

```
.data 
prompt1     byte    "Welcome to Low level I/O programming , Assignment6.asm, I am your Programmer Jackson Miller :)",0
prompt2     byte    "Ths will prompt you for 10 unsigned integears, make sure they can fit into a 32 bit register. After you enter 10 raw ints, I will display the list, sum, and average value",0
prompt3     byte    " Please enter a unsigned integear: ",0
prompt4     byte    " Invalid Entry",0
input       byte    200 dup(0)
list        dword   20 dup(0)   
num         dword   ?
temp        dword   ?
test1       byte    "How many times it get here",0
main PROC
    push    offset prompt1
    push    offset prompt2
    call    introduction
    mov     ecx,10
    mov     edi, offset list
    mov     ebx,0
    mov     edx,0
    fillnumbers:
    push    ecx
    push    edx
    displaystring    prompt3
    push    offset  input
    call    readval
    pop     edx
    mov     [edi+edx],eax
    add     edx,4
    pop     ecx
    loop    fillnumbers

    mov     esi, offset list
    mov     ecx,10
    mov     ebx,0
    displayints:
    mov     eax, [esi+ebx]
    call    writedec
    add     ebx,4
    loop    displayints

    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

readval     PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    retry:
    mov     edx, [ebp+8]
    getstring   edx
    mov     esi,edx
    mov     ecx,0
    check: 
    lodsb
    cmp     ax,0
    je      done
    cmp     ax,57
    jle     good
    jmp     notgood
    good:
    cmp     ax,48
    jge     doublegood
    jmp     notgood

    doublegood:
    sub     ax,48
    mov     ebx,10
    xchg    eax,ecx
    mul     ebx
    add     ecx,eax
    mov     eax,0
    jmp     check

    notgood:
    mov     edx,offset prompt4
    call    writestring
    call    crlf
    mov     edx, offset prompt3
    call    writestring
    jmp     retry

    done:
    mov     eax,ecx
    call    writedec
    pop     ebp
    ret     4


readval     ENDP




    displaystring           MACRO input
        push    edx
        mov     edx, offset input
        call    writestring
        pop     edx

    ENDM



    getstring       MACRO buffer
        push    edx
        mov     edx,buffer
        call    readstring
        pop     edx

    ENDM
```

Comment: You are talking about the `writedec` procedure, right? Unfortunately, you did not post the `writedec` procedure...

Comment: Don't use `loop` in the first place, if you want ECX for something else inside the loop.  Use a call-preserved register.  (In Irvine32's calling convention, all registers are call-preserved, except the return value if any.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't fully understand the question: At which moment `ecx` does not have the value expected?

Answer (score 1):

Irvine32 `ReadString` has **2** args according to [the documentation](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm):

- EDX points to the input buffer
- ECX max number of non-null chars to read

At the point where you use your `getstring` macro to call it, ECX holds `main`'s loop counter, so your max-length character limit decreases with each outer-loop iteration.

Pick a different register for your loop counter, like EDI or EBX, so you can either leave ECX set to your buffer length or let `readval` destroy ECX.

The `loop` instruction is slow on all modern CPUs except AMD Bulldozer/Ryzen, so you shouldn't use it in the first place, except if you're optimizing for code size.  But if you are, *and* it's actually convenient to use a down-counter in ECX, then sure.  Otherwise loop a different way, e.g.
`dec edi` / `jnz  top_of_loop`.

---

Other bugs:

`lodsb` / `cmp ax,0`: you didn't zero EAX, and `lodsb` is sort of like `mov al, [esi]` / `inc esi`.  So the upper byte of AX might be non-zero here.  It makes no sense to check it, if you're looking for the zero terminator.

ReadString returns `EAX` = size of input string, so in practice (except for very long inputs) only the low byte of EAX will be non-zero, and `lodsb` replaces it.  So your code happens to work for normal inputs.

Still, it's a lot easier to just stop at the first non-digit by checking for that instead of 0 and non-digit separately.  You could use that ReadString return value as a down-counter, but if you're checking for other non-digit inputs to end your loop,

```
   ... get string input
    xor   eax, eax
    jmp  first_iteration_starts_here
top_of_loop:
    imul  eax, 10
    add   eax, edx

first_iteration_starts_here:
    movzx   edx, [esi]
    inc     esi

    sub  edx, '0'
 ;; EDX = an integer from 0 .. 9   else out of bounds
    cmp  edx, 9
    jbe  top_of_loop         ; *unsigned* compare catches low characters that wrapped, too

   ; EDX = some non-digit character minus '0'
   ; total in EAX.
    ret
```

You're writing 32-bit code so you should use [2 or 3-operand `imul` for integer multiply](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html) unless you actually *want* the high-half result.  You don't have to suffer through using the inconvenient and less-efficient 1-operand `mul`.